Finding an approximation for the complete elliptic integral of the first kind $K(k)$
Finding an approximation for the complete elliptic integral of the first kind $K(k)$
In this question the author find the following approximation to the integral:
$$ I(k) := \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\sin^2(a)+k^2\cos^2(a)}\,da \approx \dfrac{\pi k}{\left(|k|+1\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{|k|+1}\right)}:= g(k) \label{Eq. 1}\tag{Eq. 1}$$
which works pretty good as you could see in Desmos.

In the same question, in the following answer it is stated that the integral $I(k)$ is related to the complete elliptic integral of the second kind $E(k)$ as:
$$I(k) = \sqrt{k^2}E\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{k^2}}\right)$$
and since the complete integral of the first kind $K(k)$ is related to the second kind ones $E(k)$ as:
$$E(k) = \left(1+\sqrt{1-k^2}\right)\cdot E\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-k^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-k^2}}\right)-\sqrt{1-k^2}\cdot K(k)$$
I want to find an approximation of $K(k)$ in terms of $g(k)$ but I got stack on the modulus transformations, but in principle it looks it is possible to isolate $K(k)$ in terms of $E(k)$ such the approximation $g(k)$ could be introduced:
Could you find an approximation for $K(k)$ in terms of the approximation $g(k)$??

Motivation__________
In this another question I was trying to find some formula for the logarithm of large numbers, and in this answer is shown the following approximation:
$$\ln(x)\approx\frac{\pi}{2M\big(1,2^{2-m}/x\big)}-m\ln(2)$$
where $M(x,y)$ is arithmetic-geometric mean, and in Wikipedia is stated that this mean is related to the complete elliptic integral of the first kind as:
$$M(x,y) = \frac{\pi}{4}\cdot \dfrac{x+y}{K\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)}$$
and I aim to figure out if a good approximation could be built using $g(k)$.

As Wikipedia also points out ("Since the arithmetic–geometric process converges so quickly, ...", they write,) computing $M(x,y)$ directly in that way is a very efficient way. Whatever approximation you can make by using $g(k)$ will be inferior in accuracy and may even be worse in speed of computation. But admittedly, $g(k)$ can be written down more clearly than the AGM algorithm. Or else what is the reason you want to use it instead of using AGM directly?

@JosBergervoet I want to find a formula based on classic basic functions like trigonometric and polynomials, looking to find intuition about why other approximations shown in my other question works as they do. An since I found a formula that it is based just in a simple trig/polynomial I think it is possible to find one.

See my answer below, I also posted a question about the precise argument definition: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4901060

The initial expression can be rewritten using $\theta=\pi/2-a$, as:
$$
I(k) = \int_\limits{0}^{\pi/2}\hspace{-1ex} da\ \sqrt{\sin^2 a +k^2\cos^2 a}
 = \int_\limits{0}^{\pi/2}\hspace{-1ex} da\ \sqrt{1 - (1-k^2)\cos^2a} \\
= \int_\limits{0}^{\pi/2}\hspace{-1ex} d\theta\ \sqrt{1 - (1-k^2)\sin^2\theta}
= E(\sqrt{1-k^2}), \tag{1}
$$
where the last step is just using the definition of Wikipedia. This is of course the same as the expression you obtained from this answer, so that just proves that $k\ E\big(\sqrt{1-\frac1{k^2}}\big) = E(\sqrt{1-k^2})$.
Renaming $k$ as $q$, from $(1)$ we get $E(\sqrt{1-q^2}) = I(q)$ and we can derive:
$$\begin{align}
E(k) &= I\big(\sqrt{1-k^2}\big), \quad\text{by solving}\ \ k=\sqrt{1-q^2}
  \ \ \text{for}\ \ q, \ \ \text{and}
\\[5pt]
E\Big(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-k^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-k^2}}\Big)
  &= I\Big(\frac{2(1 - k^2)^{1/4}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - k^2}}\Big)
 \quad\text{by solving}\ \ \frac{1-\sqrt{1-k^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-k^2}} =\sqrt{1-q^2}
\end{align}$$
We then have the two values of $E$ that we need to use the relation:
$$E(k) = \big(1+\sqrt{1-k^2}\big)  E\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-k^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-k^2}}\right)-\sqrt{1-k^2}\ K(k),$$
which then leads to:
$$K(k) = -\frac{I\big(\sqrt{1-k^2}\big)}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}
  +\frac{\big(1+\sqrt{1-k^2}\big)}{\sqrt{1 - k^2}}\ I\Big(\frac{2(1 - k^2)^{1/4}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - k^2}}\Big)$$
And of course we can now try to use the approximation by $g$ for both occurrences of $I$, which would give us:
$$K(k) \approx -\frac{g\big(\sqrt{1-k^2}\big)}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}
  +\frac{\big(1+\sqrt{1-k^2}\big)}{\sqrt{1 - k^2}}\ g\Big(\frac{2(1 - k^2)^{1/4}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - k^2}}\Big).$$
Since this is clearly a function of $k^2$, we can plot it for negative $k^2$ as well. Here's a plot from $k^2=-10$ to $1$:

Fig.1. $K(k)$ versus $k^2$ (blue) and the approximation (red).

Fig.2. The relative error in the approximation (percentage).
As can be seen the error is less than 0.5% over most of the range, but when we approach the singularity at $k=1$, we get an error of up to 50%:

Fig.3. Relative error in the approximation (percentage) for $k\rightarrow 1$.

Thank you very much for the answer. Unfortunately the small differences got important when trying to fit the natural logarithm as could be seen in Desmos

Assuming $k>0$ and
$$g= \dfrac{\pi k}{\left(k+1\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{k+1}\right)}$$ we could try to compute the inverse
$$x=\frac{\pi  k}{k+1}\qquad \implies \qquad \frac 1 g=\frac{\sin (x)}{x}$$
You can have a good approximation of $\frac{\sin (x)}{x}$ using the $[2n,2n]$ Padé approximants $P_n$ such as
$$P_1=\frac {1-\frac{7}{60}x^2} {1+\frac{1 }{20}x^2}\qquad \text{or}\qquad P_2=\frac {1-\frac{53 }{396}x^2+\frac{551 }{166320} x^4} {1+\frac{13 }{396}x^2+\frac{5 }{11088}x^4}$$ whose errors are respectively $\frac{11 x^6}{50400}$ and  $\frac{11 x^{10}}{457228800}$.
To give an idea of the accuracy
$$\Phi_n=\int_0^\pi \Bigg(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}-P_n \Bigg)^2\, dx$$ they are respectively $\Phi_1=3.01\times 10^{-3}  $ and $\Phi_2=2.78\times 10^{-7}$.
If you prefer series expansion followed by series reversion
$$x=t+\frac{t^3}{40}+\frac{107 t^5}{67200}+O\left(t^7\right)\qquad \text{wher}\qquad t=\sqrt{\frac{6(g-1)}{g}}$$
So, you have $k(g)$.
